# typescript no error even though type is not matched

Tags: typescript

```
type path= {
    col(...args: any[]): string
    doc(...args: any[]): string
}

export const creator =  <
    C extends path['col'],
    D extends path['doc']
>(pathGenerator: {
    col: C
    doc: D
}) => pathGenerator

export const profile = creator({
    col({ userId }:{ userId: string }) {
        return 'user' + '/' + userId
    },
    doc({ userId, profileId }: { userId: string, profileId: string }) {
        return this.col() + '/' + profileId // doesnt error eventhough some member is missing in this.col argument
    },
})

profile.col() // error shown correctly
```

consider this piece of code

there is no error even though in the tooltip it clearly needs an argument

[image]

however, the error is shown correctly if we try to access col via profile

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGwAsC8UDeBYAUASAMYHsAbACgDpzYAnAcwGcAuKWAOxAG0BdASkduEoCWzalmwATfLjIUaDJq048ofQcKwBfLFggAPMPkrAoBZn2OUI8A1BRQAPKIDCUXcAjMxtGPARsA5ASEfhwANKIAIi46bh5ecIj+ErjBWAB8xPEIAOLuEJRWlIwYOIGMjqJJjOEaXDap3og5zHkFWpi6+obG+KZGYJT4AGYChNAouBYFxMV4RNNQAK60eQCSYlDq9KiLy5RrvPxC1Bu1M9gWwAuUzFB+S3l+UADUtwD0jy-3e2Ki6mE4SXmXzWIRgA2GozWGyKO1WYgOqmooP6QxGEH2ykOwhOaFE5wgl2uUEQAlopECxFqLz872eYNRkPWr1eUAkEFozCMeQGlBcADd3Ih8AtqAhlPgALbQKUSgBGeSgpKgEtJtCOipuJLJgSYNAWUs5v3+6i4bRREIg5LmtWZLkoPOUCHwAHcbgR7RBcMBCCAgA)

questions:

1. why is this happening?
2. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I see the error that you posted, but if I hover *just right* I see the generic definition with `(...args: any[])`.

[image]

Both `col` and `doc` are functions which return a `string`.  If I use the generic to designate the args rather than the whole function, everything works as expected and I get an error.  Does that work for you?

```
export const creator =  <
    C extends {},
    D extends {}
>(pathGenerator: {
    col: (props: C) => string,
    doc: (props: D) => string
}) => pathGenerator

export const profile = creator({
    col({ userId }:{ userId: string }) {
        return 'user' + '/' + userId
    },
    doc({ userId, profileId }: { userId: string, profileId: string }) {
        return this.col() + '/' + profileId // shows error!
    },
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wVYBDG04C8ccAPALABQAkAMJygzDIAmqcA3gL4A0lVAIvRCMWbLpQB8ACjC4AFgHEmwKLmgAuDnyQAbTTKgQwqTTQCUhCXHRQAlsgDmvaswgJ9YQ8c38LBKzb2DpScflayMIrKqnhQlJSgkLCIKOhwnhAAZrY6wISIWGpQUuzaEDolcACuqCoAksxwnOrs1bVQDZqBjk0WpdRUWDBVUMhwAOQ1KuNwANQTAPQz81MdzHw8fK4IlasN3OmG2bkNTZqte8xdMHaOBxnHwJ3WN0G9WgNDI2ORtqgAdLopBZ5uMlnNDlkck91tRNhRQkA)

Comment: not working because<< return this.col({userId})>> would also error

Comment: Ugh I didn't think to check that.  It works if you move the type definition from each function to the creator instead, but I don't love this. `creator<{ userId: string }, { userId: string, profileId: string }>`